# Spring Boot Property Resolution passed into command line parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I would like to use a separate `.env` file later on to read the properties from, but now I am just passing in the properties to the Spring `runApplication` function to see what is working.

#### Case 1)

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: ${SPRING_SERVER_PORT}
```

`WebApplication.kt`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<WebApplication>(
            "--SPRING_SERVER_PORT", "8085"
    )
}
```

`Outcome`

Server starts at port 8080. (NOT 8085 !!!)

#### Case 2)

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: ${SPRING_SERVER_PORT}
```

`WebApplication.kt`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<WebApplication>()
}
```

`Outcome`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'SPRING_SERVER_PORT' in value "${SPRING_SERVER_PORT}"`

#### Case 3)

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8081
```

`WebApplication.kt`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<WebApplication>()
}
```

`Outcome`

Server starts at port 8081.

---

Does that actually mean Spring cannot parse a String and fails silently when doing so?

What am I doing wrong?

---

Project created from latest spring boot initializer:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the args this way:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<WebApplication>(
            "--SPRING_SERVER_PORT=8085"
    )
}
```

Like the way you would pass it on the command line